# How to inject a worker class into a ServerSocket implementation?

Tags: java, dependency-injection, serversocket

I'm looking to create a generic TCP/IP server using ServerSocket that can be used by multiple projects my team is working on. The hurdle I'm facing is how best to inject a Runnable worker class since various projects will have different functionality for interacting with the client.

Here's what I've got now:

```
Socket clientSocket = serverSocket.accept();
Runnable worker = WorkerFactory.getWorker(interfaceId, clientSocket, id);
Thread t = new Thread(worker, "Client #" + id);
t.start();
```

Passing the `interfaceId` into the server works for a subset of the projects, but when all the possible uses are considered it's not a viable solution.

I'm thinking a factory using generics, or possibly somehow using the Spring framework, may be the way to go but I'm a little vague on how to go about that. I've searched and I've been unable to find anything about injecting workers for a ServerSocket implementation. Any suggestions would be appreciated...

Answer (score 0):

I can't quite tell how far along you are here so excuse the obvious statements.

There are a number of ways that you can go here.  It depends a lot on how much work your server framework wants to do for the callers.  For example, it could just accept the sockets and then call `handle` with the `Socket` or the associated input and output streams.  Or your framework could take an object and an array of interfaces to proxy.  The client could send a string and an array of objects and you could invoke the methods on injected proxies.

It seems like you are implying that some clients can be handled as a proxy interface but others need lower level access to the input/output streams.  So you could have your simplest `ClientHandler` interface that the clients have to implement something like:

```
public interface ClientHandler {
    public void handleClient(InputStream, OutputStream) throws Exception;
}
```

Your framework could then provide various implementations/wrappers.  One could be a proxy handler which would handle clients calls as an `ObjectInputStream` and output stream.  The client could write a method-name and the object array for the arguments:

```
public class ProxyHandler implements ClientHandler {
    private Object handler;
    public ProxyHandler(Object handler) {
       this.handler = handler;
    }
    public void handleClient(InputStream input, OutputStream output) throws Exception {
       // creates the object i/o streams
       // reads method string, object array, looks up methods in the handler obj by name
       // loop until done
    }
}
```

The framework could provide other handlers that dealt with line-by-line protocols and the like.

```
public interface LineByLineHandler {
    public String handleLine(String line);
}
```

And the wrapper:

```
public class LineByLineHandlerWrapper implements ClientHandler {
    private LineByLineHandler handler;
    public ProxyHandler(LineByLineHandler handler) {
       this.handler = handler;
    }
    public void handleClient(InputStream input, OutputStream output) throws Exception {
       // creates the buffered i/o reader/writes
       // reads a string string, calls the handler, writes the response
       // loop until done
    }
}
```

So the basic handler would be the `ClientHandler` and the more features could be provided by the `ProxyHandler`, `LineByLineHandler`, etc..

Hope this helps.  Sorry if this is all obvious.  Comment and I'll increase the level of specificity.